# cmake if ( DEFINED ) Not working properly

Tags: cmake

I have the below snippet of the code:

```
message("TARGET_NAME=${TARGET_NAME}") 

string(TOUPPER "${TARGET_NAME}_BUILDTYPE" TARGET_BUILDTYPE)
message("TARGET_BUILDTYPE=${TARGET_BUILDTYPE}") 

if(DEFINED ${TARGET_BUILDTYPE})
    set(TG_BUILDTYPE ${${TARGET_BUILDTYPE}})
    message("TG_BUILDTYPE=\"${TG_BUILDTYPE}\"")
else()
    message( FATAL_ERROR "cm_add_variable_target() was called, but no target 
    type variable is found")
endif()
```

Output is:

> TARGET_NAME="DSE_Utilities"
>
> TARGET_BUILDTYPE=DSE_UTILITIES_BUILDTYPE
>
> CMake Error at dep/buildspec/cmake-common.cmake:605 (message):
>   cm_add_variable_target() was called, but no target type variable is
>   found Call Stack (most recent call first):
>   src/DSE_Utilities/CMakeLists.txt:31 (cm_add_variable_target)

Why is it not getting into if code?

Comment: Hi  Florian, Yes I have seen the other question but that did not help solve my problem. I was not sure if i should ask new question or to continue on that old one explaining my problem. I am new to asking questions here.

Answer (score 2):

Your syntax is slightly off, the $ and curly braces should not be used here. It should be:

```
if (DEFINED TARGET_BUILDTYPE)
    ...
else()
    ...
endif()
```

Doing `if(DEFINED ${TARGET_BUILDTYPE})` causes CMake to expand the variable and look for a variable named by the result of the expansion. (In your case it ends up checking if a variable named DSE_UTILITIES_BUILDTYPE is defined)

See [CMake's if() command documentation](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/command/if.html) for more info.

Comment: Any idea what is the meaning of using ${${ as shown below.    set(TG_BUILDTYPE ${${TARGET_BUILDTYPE}})

Comment: @BaskaraReddy It using the value of TARGET_BUILDTYPE to construct a variable name. e.g. After TARGET_BUILDTYPE is expanded, the line looks like: `${DSE_UTILITIES_BUILDTYPE}`. Then finally, the DSE_UTILITIES_BUILDTYPE variable would get expanded.

Comment: Thanks @mshildt for clarifying on that.